# Use expect.Expect for Groovy to SSH on specific port

Tags: groovy, ssh, scripting, expect

Have a simple groovy script as follows (terribly formatted):

```
import com.santaba.agent.groovyapi.expect.Expect
def hostname = hostProps.get("system.hostname")

cli = Expect.open(hostname, "user", "pass")
cli.expect("*** Welcome to pfSense ")
cli.send("8\n")

cli.expect("root(1): ")
cli.send( "relayctl show hosts\n" )
cli.expect("root(2): ")

cli.before().eachLine { line ->
   if ( line =~ /host/ ) {
      tokens = line.split(/\s+/)
      println tokens[5]
   }
}
cli.send("exit\n")
cli.close()
```

What I'm unable to do is to pass in the PORT I'd like for it to SSH on, for example: 8331.

Is it possible to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can send in the port number as part of the `.open` call:

```
cli = Expect.open(hostname, 8331, 5)//port 8331, 5 connection retries
```

Should be able to figure the rest of the commands from the logic monitor [docs](http://help.logicmonitor.com/using/datasource/creating-datasources/collectors/script-collector/groovy-support/emulate-text-based-protocol-interaction/)